# WC3 Validation problems, Cant find row

Tags: php, html, validation, rows

When im about to validate my website, i get this error:

Row: 279  Column: 3

```
<?php include("byline.php"); ?>     Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.).
```

The website I did the validation to only has 74 rows and not 279. There are some included files with around 40-80 rows/file. How do I find this 279:th row?? 
(I have searched through all files after "`<?php include("byline.php"); ?>`" with no results...)

Comment: Your actual file has PHP extension? (.php) I mean the one you use to show all not `byline.php`

Comment: Yes all files has PHP extension. If thats what you mean.

Comment: Have you checked your server's set up is ok?

Comment: wc3 validation is concerned with html output. Row 279 refers to the generated html. As to why the php tag is being output into html is another issue

Answer (score 0):

You have no results because you're searching on the output.
In the index of the inspected file you should have the include to the byline.php.

Even if your file only has 74 lines, the include will be in the output and therefore the final rendered result will be bigger.

It can also happen that the byline.php is not included inside the main file but within even another one, I mean;

`<?php include('first_include.php'); ?>`

and inside it, your:

`<?php include('byline.php'); ?>`

The best way is to search for includes in the index and go from there.